# mapping strings to functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dictionary

I'd like to make it so that based on the value of an HTML attribute in a list of HTML elements, that I can call a different javascript function based on the value of that attribute's string value.

basically what I want is a map from string => function in javascript / jQuery. (and then of course be able to call this function).

is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes:

```
var fnMap = {
  "foo": function() { ... },
  "bar": function() { ... },
  // ...
};
```

If your functions already exist, you can just reference them by name:

```
var fnMap = {
  "foo": someFunction,
  "bar": otherFunction,
  // ...
};
```

and you can mix the two styles.

To call one of the functions based on a value:

```
fnMap[ value ]( param, param, ... );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I would have suggested, except that I'd probably wrap the actual call in an `if (fnMap[value]) { fnMap[value](); }` so that there are no reference errors in the case that something was poorly-formed along the way.  That said, the reference errors might be a help in the right debugging tool (just not at production time).

Comment: Yes that's a very good point, @Norguard - it depends on the situation of course; if the value comes from a `<select>` element then it might be safe to assume it's OK, but a check like that is so cheap there's no reason not to do it.

Comment: Absolutely.  And the reason I suggested it wasn't necessarily because of the `select` deal, but because the pattern of having functions referenced by string is so easy (and if they're enclosed) so relatively-safe from the pitfalls of other similar methods (like `eval`), that doing this regularly, on say, a list of song-items, to play the song with the function in the value -- or in the value of the container object, with a listener, and the name of the song in the target item, itself (used as a parameter), there's no reason not to do something like this, and it leaves your HTML sparkling-clean

Comment: this is great! just what I was looking for

Comment: I'm attempting to do something similar, but instead create a type for the var, so other methods can know what to expect.  I tried something like:    `function foo(): string { return prompt("Input","foo"); }
   function bar(): string { return prompt("Input","bar"); }
   
    var params: { [index: string]: () => string; } = {
        "foo": foo(),
        "bar": bar()
    }
 ` but no love, any thoughts? Woops was trying to do this in typescript...probably a bit different

Comment: @ericpeters I suspect there's a way to do it in Typescript, but I'm not familiar with it so I can't offer much in the way of suggestions.

Comment: y u no use `.hasOwnProperty()` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯